# Orthongonally diagonalize the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

Orthongonally diagonalize the matrix A, by finding an orthongonal matrix Q, and a diagonal mathrix D, such that $Q^{t}AQ=D$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
  5 & 6 & 0 \\
  6 & 5 & 8 \\
  0 & 8 & 5
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\det(A) = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
5-\lambda & 6 & 0 \\
6 & 5-\lambda & 8 \\
0 & 8 & 5-\lambda \end{array} \right|=0$$

$$\lambda=15,5,-5$$

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
  15 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 5 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -5
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$...$$

$$(A-15I) = \begin{bmatrix}
  -10 & 6 & 0 \\
  6 & -10 & 8 \\
  0 & 8 & -10
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$-10x_{1} + 6x_{2} = 0$$
$$8x_{2} -10x_{3} = 0$$
$$v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}
  ?\\
?\\
?\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

$$...$$

$$(A-5I) = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 6 & 0 \\
  6 & 0 & 8 \\
  0 & 8 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$6x_{1} + 8x_{3} = 0$$

$$v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
  ?\\
?\\
?\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

$$...$$

$$(A+5I) = \begin{bmatrix}
  10 & 6 & 0 \\
  6 & 10 & 8 \\
  0 & 8 & 10
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$10x_{1} + 6x_{2} = 0$$
$$6x_{1} + 10x_{2} = 0$$
$$8x_{2} + 10x_{3} = 0$$

$$v_{3} = \begin{bmatrix}
  ?\\
?\\
?\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I cannot decide how to make the matrices $v_{1}$,$v_{2}$,$v_{3}$, to make Q, such that $Q^{t}=Q$. How do I decide on what to put in matrix Q before I normalize it, to be sure that it is equal to its transpose???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the systems of equations in each step, i.e. find bases for the solution sets. Then use the Gramm-Schmidt procedure to turn these bases into orthonormal ones. In this case, each eigenspace has dimension one, so you only have to normalize each eigenvector. That should do it.

Comment: this doesn't help much, do you mean for example at (A-15*I), to put the matrix in reduced row echelon form, then to get the vector?

Comment: No, why did you write down that first system of equations? You need to solve the system of equations $(A-15I)X=0$, you have two independent equations and one free variable, hence the solution space has dimension one. Each non-zero solution to the equation $(A-15I)X=0$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $15$. You have to find that eigenvector and normalize it. You have to do the same thing for the other two systems of equations. Also, you got those wrong, the second system is missing an equation and the last one contains an error.

Comment: @hit: Also, you don't want that $Q^T=Q$, but rather $Q^{-1}=Q^T$. Try to show that a square matrix $A$ contains an orthonormal basis as row/columns if and only if $A^TA=I=AA^T$. Also, did you downvote my answer? If so, could you explain why?